# Updating a List<> item with previous items value

Tags: c#, list, lambda, visual-studio-2013

Lets say I have a DataContact Like this:

```
[DataContract]
public struct tblTesters
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID;

    [DataMember]
    public string Value1;

    [DataMember]
    public string Value2;        
}
```

I populate a list with the DataContract above. I now have a List. If any "Value1" inside List is null or empty then it should take the value of the previous "Value1" item within the list. The order should remain unchanged after the update.

How do I go about updating the values of the null or empty items with the previous items value?

Comment: You could use a property and write that logic in the setter.

Comment: Do you have to use the regular List<T> or a custom one is an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using simple for loop? :)

```
for (int i = 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
   myList[i].Value1 =  myList[i].Value1 ?? myList[i-1].Value1;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to stay away from a simple for loop as the data is very large in the "real world" context of this question.

Comment: @BossRoss using linq will take longer than this simple for :)

Comment: @BossRoss: A simple loop is the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

```
for( i=0; i < headerList.size();i++){   
    if(headerList.get(i).getPurchaseOrdNo()==null){
        headerList.get(i).setPurchaseOrdNo(headerList.get(i-1).getPurchaseOrdNo()); 
    }
}
```